# Sweave boxplots -- not the required output

Tags: texmaker, r, sweave

I want to produce a boxplot like this in `R`:

```
fishdata <- read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/s/4w0utkqdhqribl4/fishdata.csv", header=T)
attach(fishdata)
boxplot(fishdata[,-1], las=3)
```

which looks like this:

[image: what it should look like]

but when I Sweave this, using this coding:

```
<<echo=F>>=
fishdata <- read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/s/4w0utkqdhqribl4/fishdata.csv", header=T)
attach(fishdata)
@ 

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
<<fig=T, echo=F>>=
boxplot(fishdata[,-1], las=3)
@
\rule{35em}{0.5pt}
\caption{Boxplot of the fish catches in Bangladesh from 1950 to 2011.}
\label{histogram}
\end{figure}
```

produces this still,

[image: boxplot output]

Is there a way to get the x-axis titles as above in the coding?

Comment: I took the liberty to include a screenshot of the output you want to see because your problem at first wasn't very clear to me. Hope that's ok.

Comment: I can't reproduce this (R development version/3.1.0); simply adding `\documentclass{article}; \begin{document} ; ... \end{document}` to your MWE, I get final output with vertical x-axis labels as you wanted. (Have you tried clearing out any previously created plot files?)

Comment: @BenBolker - yes deleting the previous plots files worked! Thanks

Comment: @hgeop, perhaps post that as an answer. (You are encouraged to answer your own questions if you can.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll be your *Answer the Unanswered* officer tonight;

From the comments, it has been verified that in certain cases, it might happen that in such cases deleting the previous plot files is needed.